# ReactJS passing parameters from sibling to sibling components

Tags: reactjs, components, parameter-passing

I have component tree like this:

```
<App />
  <NoteList />
    <Note />
  <Notes />
```

I'm running a function from the Notes component in the NoteList component and everything works except for passing parameters.

Here's my code:

```
<NoteList displayChange={() => this.content.displayNote()} />
<Notes
   ref={instance => {
        this.content = instance;
       }}
/>
```

Here's the displayNote function which is called via displayChange in the NoteList component

```
displayNote = test => {
  console.log("id", test)
  console.log("sibling linked!")
};
```

It's ran through a function in the NoteList component:

```
callbackFunction = childData => {
    console.log("childData", childData);
    this.props.displayChange(childData);
  };
```

so when callbackFunction is ran, the displayChange() works correctly BUT childData isn't passed correctly. What I mean is when the childData is passed as a parameter, it ends up being undefined in the console.log

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working, here's the code:

```
 callbackFunction = childData => {
    console.log("childData", childData);
    this.props.displayChange(childData);
  };

<NoteList displayChange={(id) => this.content.displayNote(id)} />
  <Notes
     ref={instance => {
       this.content = instance;
       }}
   />
```